# How to get hostname of Google Colab and make it act as a client (using python socket module)?

Tags: python, networking, client-server, google-colaboratory

I want to connect Google Colab to a program (server) that runs on my local machine, generating data to be processed. I want a program (client) running on Google Colab to receive this data.

I know how to get the IP address of my Google Colab using

```
!curl ipecho.net/plain
```

but how do I get the hostname and port number?

Also, even after I get these things, would I be able to accomplish my goal?

Has anyone tried this?

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: @SantoshGupta7 if you want to send data from local machine to cloud, you can send via drive. Send data from local machine to drive using rclone.

Comment: Also, you can send data through some other cloud like, adafruit. Colab is protected with a firewall , so most probably we wouldn't be able to connect to it even if we had ip etc.